# Explaining this expression

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

This might be a very basic and silly question but I saw an interesting equality in a question and I'm having a hard time understanding it.

Let $f(t)$ be a function in time $t \geqslant 0$ and let $c$ be a constant. The equality is $$(\partial_t + c)^2 f(t) = \frac{\partial^2 f(t)}{\partial t^2} + 2 c \frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial t} + c^2.$$

Does this equality actually hold? If yes, why?

Comment: Presumably, the last term on the right should be $c^2 f(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a formal equality. $(\partial_t+c)^2$ is to be understood as an operator acting on $f$. More specifically, as the operator $\partial_t+c$ being applied twice to $f$. So,
\begin{align*}
(\partial_t + c)^2 f =&  (\partial_t + c)(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+ cf)=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t}+c\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+c \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + c^2f\\
& =\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t}+2c\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + c^2f
\end{align*}

The same result could be obtained computing
$$
(\partial_t+c)^2 = \partial^2_t+2c\partial_t +c^2.
$$